# Inserting merge fields where the displayed text / name should differ from the field name

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I want to insert merge fields in a Word document using VBA where the displayed name of the merge field in the document should differ from the field name.

Here's an example:

The name of one of the merge field is `GD_CName` but in the Word document, the merged field should be displayed as "Company Name" to make it easier for the user afterward to understand which information will be displayed later.

Currently, I am using the following code to insert a merge field:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="GD_CName"
```

But I can´t find a parameter to define a different text that should be displayed instead of the field name.

Comment: What's the mail merge data source? This isn't somethng Word supports, but if you can put a query between the data table and Word you can use "expressions" in the query to label the data fields differntly.

Comment: If you answer my question in comments I might be able to help you...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a mergefield display a different field name from that appearing in the data source.

Comment: I mean I can do it manually. After inserting the mergefield I can just change the displayed name to "Company Name", while when I right click on the mergefield and select "Edit field" the field name hasn´t changed (still "GD_CName").

Comment: And as soon as anything happens to cause Word to refresh the field display (e.g. a merge preview or print preview), the field will revert to the normal display.